# How to do ajax loading with URL change but not page redirection?

Tags: ajax, url

If you carefully notice facebook, you will understand that the when you visit one page to another then the **whole page is not refreshed or redirected** but the **URL changes** when navigating to new page. It is *more clear when **chat windows** are open,* they **remains static during page loading**. As other website does this by using the **# but facebook does not**.

There is another example came to me: http://www.davidwalsh.name/. Visit the site and **open other pages within their site** and you will understand what I mean. Don't forget to **notice the URL change.**

How they do this?

Added More: I want a way that the page content will be loaded with ajax, change the URL for bookmark feature but when changing URL it should not reload / refresh the page by not using # (hash).

Comment: For Facebook, Google "hash navigation ajax".  For DavidWalsh, google "history API".

Comment: Great @andytuba... Thank you buddy! This is what I wanted. As you comment on this I cannot accept the answer :(

Comment: No worries, glad it helped you.  Maybe copy-pasta that and "answer my own question" just to add the checkmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @andytuba

For Facebook, Google "hash navigation ajax".

For DavidWalsh, google "history API".

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions:

For the URL change you can put the path instead of the # in the href property of the anchor (e.g /otherlink).

For opening the chat or opening some div does not require to send it in the url, its the onclick event on the div and its expands. Also the chat remains open may be thay set cookie or flag when the chat is first time opened and checking and changing the chat with flag they are setting.

Comment: Thank you @Tariq for your response. But I'm sorry you didn't understand what I'm trying to ask. I want a way that the page content will be loaded with ajax, change the URL for bookmark feature but when changing URL it should not reload / refresh the page.
The way you said will only give me a way to stay in same condition when the page redirects to another, which is not my question.

Comment: What I understand is you want to load some content with ajax but not to refresh the page using anchor. so use return false; on the onclick event of the anchor.
you can use <a href="/otherLink" onclick="return false">link</a>